# java.io.EOFException when decoding image from the web

Tags: android

I'm launching several threads for fetching images from the web. The problem is that randomally I get java.io.EOFException in one or two of the requests. This is the code I'm using, and the exception occurs on the decodeStream call:

```
InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) new URL(slot.mUrl).getContent();
mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
```

and this is the stack info:

```
java.io.EOFException
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:203)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:274)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(URLConnection.java:326)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:193)
at java.net.URL.getContent(URL.java:447)
```

Any idea what's the problem?

Thanks,
yakobom

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use universal image loader for loading image from URL because Inputstream getting null sometime in android I have used this : https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: Thanks. I saw people mentioning this loader, but I preffered to first try and handle it without another 3rd party project. Have you used it in on several images in paralel?

Answer (score 0):

There is some related questions on SO, you can find them as I did.
You may put your `inputStream.close()` in a finally block aswell because I assume you could close the stream before the process completed.
Else, try to check the sources of the lines in your stack to see where exception has been raised.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesnt really help... And I did check other questions on SO, if there's something you think I missed and I should look at - I will be happy to check it.